# EOF and PAGESIZE in mmap in C

Tags: c, linux, mmap, eof

I have this code to read a file using `mmap` and print it using `printf`. The file has 10 lines, and contains nos `0-9` on each line.

**My questions are:**
 1. Why my code doesn't terminate on `EOF` ? i.e. why doesn't it stop at `while (data[i]!=EOF)` ?
 2. When I run it with `while (data[i]!=EOF)`, the program always terminates at `data[10567]` ? where as the page size is `4096 bytes`. Does `10567` bytes have any significance ?

**Edit:** I am not looking for alternative like using `fscanf`, `fgets`.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
 10 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 11 {
 12         FILE *ifp, *ofp;
 13         int pagesize, fd, i=0;
 14         char *data;
 15         struct stat sbuf;
 16
 18         if ((ifp = fopen("/home/t/workspace/lin", "r"))==NULL)
 19         {
 20                 fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file\n");
 21                 exit(1);
 22         }
 28         fd  = fileno(ifp);
 29         if (stat("/home/t/workspace/lin", &sbuf) == -1)
 30         {
 31                 perror("stat");
 32                 exit(1);
 33         }
 34         pagesize = getpagesize();
 35         printf("page size: %d\n", pagesize);
 36         printf("file size: %d\n", sbuf.st_size);
 37         if((data = mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (caddr_t)(-1))
 38         {
 39                 perror("mmap");
 40                 exit(1);
 41         }
 43         //while (data[i]!=EOF)
 44         while (i<=sbuf.st_size)
 45         {
 46                 printf("data[%d]=%c\n", i, data[i]);
 47                 i++;
 48         }
 50         return 0;
 51 }
```

**Output:**

```
page size: 4096
file size: 21
data[0]=0
data[1]=

data[2]=1
data[3]=

data[4]=2
data[5]=

data[6]=3
data[7]=

data[8]=4
data[9]=

. . . .

data[18]=9
data[19]=

data[20]=

data[21]=  // truncated my output here, 
           // it goes till data[10567] if I use `while (data[i]!=EOF)`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`EOF` is not stored in files. So there's no point comparing a byte from the file with `EOF`. If you use `mmap`, as opposed to `getchar` or equivalent, then you need to `stat` the file to find out how big it is.

Note that `getc`, `fgetc` and `getchar` return an `int`. Quoting the manpage (or the Posix standard), these functions return the next byte "as an unsigned char cast to an int, or `EOF` on end of file or error." The value of `EOF` must be such that it cannot be confused with "an unsigned char cast to an int"; typically, it is -1. It *is* possible for a random (signed) `char` to be equal to `-1`, so your test `data[i]!=EOF` may eventually turn out to be true as you scan through uninitialized memory, if you don't segfault before you hit the random byte.

In Unix, text files are not necessarily terminated with NULs either. In short, you should only try to reference bytes you know to be inside the file, based on the file's size.

Comment: If it is not stored in files then how can `getc` or `fscanf` use it ?

Comment: Okay, so EOF is a signal generated by the OS indicating the end of file. Can you comment on the other question also ? Thanks!

Comment: @brokenfoot: I hope the edit I just made answers your question.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense. So, my program terminating at `10567` bytes is just a co-incidence where the byte that it reads is equal to `-1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You output looks correct. The only bug I see is that:

```
   while (i<=sbuf.st_size)
```

should have `<`.

There is no `EOF`, such as a `Control-Z`, stored in the actual data. All standard functions such as `getc` will return `EOF` when their internal counter equivalent to your `i` is past but their own `sbuf.st_size`.  That is to say, `EOF` is a fictitious character generated by `getc` and/or the OS.

The confusion perhaps arises because, if I recall correctly, MS-DOS *text* files actually contain a `^Z`, and if you inadvertently `fopen` one in *binary* mode, you can see this unwanted `^Z`. Unix does not have this distinction.

With respect to your question:

> Does `10567` bytes have any significance ?

I would say ***no***. My guess is that `data[10567]` happens to be the first byte of memory equal to `0xFF`, which is promoted to `-l` (assuming your `char` is signed), which matches `EOF`.

Comment: Yes, that should be just a `<`, can you comment on the other question that I have ?

Comment: So, is `EOF` generated by the `OS` ?